# What is an exact field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, terminology

In the following paper I found the term exact field:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10658.pdf

Does someone know what it means?

Comment: Never heard that term.

Comment: Published in 2017, so odds are the authors are still alive, and their emails (right there with their names) still work.  Asking a question about their publication is a fair use for that…

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvotes? Is this not a valid question?

Comment: Terminology isn't universal. Relevant definitions should be available in the context of what you're reading.

Comment: It's a perfectly good question and I don't understand why it was closed.  How on earth could this question be made more clear than it already is?

Comment: For what it's worth, given the context I would guess an "exact field" is something like a field whose operations are computable (the idea being that it is field in which you can compute "exact" values).

Comment: In this case, I think "exact" describes how elements of the field are represented on a computer. An exact field is one in which each element can be represented (exactly!) using finitely many bits; e.g., $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$. In contrast, most elements of a precision or inexact field can only be represented as approximations up to some precision; e.g., elements of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are represented as truncations with only finitely many decimal or $p$-adic digits. [This paper mentions this usage of the word "exact"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.03740.pdf).

Comment: I checked a number of the papers that that paper cites, and also a number of other papers by the same authors, and did not find the term "exact field" anywhere.  The authors should be castigated for not defining it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking one of the coauthors via E-Mail he confirmed the idea of @Eric Wofsey. An exact field is a field in which you can realize exact computation.